# Stack Overflow showing 1 reputation even though I have more than 200

Tags: support, jobs

I'm trying to build out my Careers 2.0 profile by connecting to a Stack Exchange account with 200+ rep. My Stack Overflow account has more than 200 rep, but the area where I can connect the account shows only 1 rep.

This is what I see:

> [image: Notice SO account with 1 rep]

The frustrating part is my account profile for meta.stackexchange.com does not display my SO account, but I do have one: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1842294/seth.

Has anyone encountered this and found a solution?

Comment: I don't see a SO profile connected with this SE profile. Do you have a separate SO login? http://stackexchange.com/users/1451630/seth?tab=accounts

Comment: That's very odd. I do have a SO account that uses the same email: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1842294/seth

Comment: You'll need to contact team@stackoverflow.com to get this straightened. For some reason your SO account isn't showing on your Network profile. Unfortunately I only have support access to Careers issue so there's not much I can do.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. This was an issue with Stack exchange accounts. The flagged answer did not occur, nor did it solve my question. My problem was solved by the Stack Exchange team due to account divergence  when changing an email.